# fugashi installing and arm64 discrepancy

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I have tried to install `fugashi`
on `Mac M1 (Ventura)`
with `pyenv`

```
pip install fugashi
Collecting fugashi
  Using cached fugashi-1.2.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl
Installing collected packages: fugashi
Successfully installed fugashi-1.2.1
```

to me that looks like the arm64 version was correctly used.
However, when I try to run this script in python

```
from fugashi import Tagger

tagger = Tagger('-Owakati')
text = "麩菓子は、麩を主材料とした日本の菓子。"
tagger.parse(text)
for word in tagger(text):
    print(word, word.feature.lemma, word.pos, sep='\t')
```

it says

```
dlopen(/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
  File "/Users/mypc/Git/Research/Python/languageprocessing/fugashiparser.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fugashi import Tagger
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fugashi/fugashi.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

so I tried to [follow another guide](https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3/issues/87) that recommended building from source:
`ARCHFLAGS='-arch arm64' pip install --compile --use-pep517 --no-cache-dir --force fugashi`
however when I run that it says my pip is outdated, even when I upgrade.

```
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

notice that this only happens if I build from source, otherwise pip is not indicating issues AND `pip --version`gives the correct 23.1

that bugs me a bit, as I used to have an error like that before and after weeks found out, that in a pip.conf there was a wrong path in place (it was none of the bashrc or zshrc files), but now I am using pyenv and I don't find any pip.conf files to check. since it only happens when I install from source I assume there is an incompatibility of paths with the pip thats used for that?

if I install normally with pip, other packages work fine and pip will not request an update (and is already updated to the newest version)

I have tried these 2 but they also dont have a solution for me:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099893/mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-x86-64-need-arm64e-m1)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308682/mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-x86-64-need-arm64e)
there it was also suggested its an error with pyenv
"This will not be answer to your question/specific situation (most probably), but I got this issue when using python built for pyenv/virtualenv, and rm -rf ~/.pyenv helped me. So, python was reinstalled (properly this time; reinstalled by other scripts in our CI, because I deleted installation), and it's built for x86 and works fine on arm."